# Cannot install a package because dependency is not a real package

Tags: apt, 20.04, dependencies

Really can't add anything to the log below. Please kindly advise?

```
zorath@zorath-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install ./cav-linux_x64.deb 
[sudo] password for zorath: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'cav-linux' instead of './cav-linux_x64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cav-linux : Depends: libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8m-1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
zorath@zorath-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ apt show libssl0.9.8
Package: libssl0.9.8
State: not a real package (virtual)
N: Can't select candidate version from package libssl0.9.8 as it has no candidate
N: Can't select versions from package 'libssl0.9.8' as it is purely virtual
N: No packages found
```

**ETA:** So, the real problem here is not with the package being virtual, but that it does not exist in the repositories at all, right?

Comment: that's an ancient lib that wasn't available anymore since Xenial (16.04). 20.04 comes with libssl 1.1.1 iirc, so you can try `sudo dpkg –ignore-depends=libssl0.9.8 -i cav-linux_x64.deb` to not install that dependency, someone on the internet claims it should work. An antivirus using old libssl is kinda sketchy though...

Comment: @Esther The software I'm trying to install comes from a very reputable corporation and is marked '2022'. Of course, Comodo could make a ridiculous mistake here but... uh?

Comment: I really have no idea why they don't update to use newer libssl, but anyways it will possibly work with the updated libssl (and why they don't update their dependency requirements is beyond me). Alternatively you can download and install libssl0.9.8, but installing older versions of packages with older requirements can cause other dependency issues, etc, so trying to get it to work with the built-in libssl is probably better.

Comment: Just wonder if [this is](https://www.comodo.com/home/download/download.php?prod=antivirus-for-linux) the very reputable web page you got the .deb from. It happens to mention Ubuntu 12.04 and Debian 6.0, so I am not surprised. Yeap, [here is another](https://www.linuxexperten.com/content/free-comodo-antivirus-linux-2022), that doen't require javascript. Same odd selection of distros.

Comment: @mikewhatever Yep. I missed this part and now that I checked their whatsnew, the last update was in 2013. At least I learned a lot about Ubuntu package management.

Answer (score 2):

*Resolution*: find another `.deb` installation file that is compatible with your current system. Lacking one, your only option may be to compile the application yourself.

`.deb` installation packages are far from universal. They only can be installed on a system that has, or can install, the dependencies at the version expected by the `.deb`.

Thus, a `.deb`has to be packaged for your specific Ubuntu version, or you must be lucky, where the `.deb` does not require dependencies your current system cannot satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of installing would be:

```
cd Downloads
wget https://cdn.download.comodo.com/cis/download/installs/linux/cav-linux_x64.deb
sudo apt install libssl1.1 -y
sudo dpkg --ignore-depends=libssl0.9.8 -i cav-linux_x64.deb
```

Post-installation script:

```
sudo /opt/COMODO/post_setup.sh
```

I would advice against it and stick to official repositories. anti virus has no added value on a Linux desktop.